# Merge UIStatusBar and UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

How can I get the navigationbar in my iPhone application to match the one in other apps such as Safari as the time and bar are merged.  Here's what mine looks like compared to MobileSafari.

**Safari**

[image]

**My App**

[image]

Thanks for your help! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem and I had the same, but solved very easily by just setting the UINavigationBar Y-position to 20px and not to 0px. Then you have to assign the UINavigationBarDelegate to your ViewController:

```
[_navigationBar setDelegate:self];
```

Furthermore you have to add this method to your ViewController, which will be called because of the Delegate assignment:

```
-(UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did It already. Safari just has a UITextField instead of a title label in the center. Navigation bars are now 64px in height for iOS 7 and automatically go under the navigation bar